# Синтаксическая ошибка: ] (C++)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, дружественная-функция

Необходимо создать дружественную функцию, которая будет выводить данные о тех автобусах, которые прибудут в место назначения раньше заданного времени.

Есть класс Bus, в котором я объявил дружественную функцию:

```
class Bus { //Создаём класс для автобусов
private:
...
    friend void showBuses(int, Bus*, Time); //Объявление дружественной функции
...
```

При вызове этой функции в программе возникает ошибка.

Вызов функции:

```
showBuses(amount, *massiv[], arrivalTime); //вызов дружественной функции
```

***massiv[]** - указатель на массив объектов класса Bus. В списке ошибок выводится "синтаксическая ошибка: ]", при этом подчёркивается символ ] в вызове функции.

Не знаю, понадобится ли, но вот определение этой функции:

```
void showBuses(int amount, Bus* massiv[], Time arrivalTime) {
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        if ((massiv[i]->getArrHour() < arrivalTime.hour) || ((massiv[i]->getArrHour() == arrivalTime.hour) && (massiv[i]->getArrMinute() < arrivalTime.minute))) {
            massiv[i]->GetBus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что вы должны передать в функцию? Массив указателей на `Bus`. А что вы передаете? Что такое у вас `massiv`?

Comment: massiv я определил вот так:
`Bus* massiv = new Bus[amount];`.
Я новичок и не очень хорошо разбираюсь. Amount - количество объектов

Comment: Итого, `massiv` у вас представляет собой массив элементов типа `Bus`, и никак в `void showBuses(int amount, Bus* massiv[],` передан быть не может... Ни так как у вас (неправильно), ни синтаксически правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас

```
Bus* massiv = new Bus[amount];
```

то объявлять функцию надо как

```
void showBuses(int amount, Bus* massiv, Time arrivalTime)
```

и передавать в нее просто `massiv`

```
showBuses(amount, massiv, arrivalTime);
```

А в самой функции работать не через `->`

```
massiv[i]->getArrHour()
```

а

```
massiv[i].getArrHour()
```